# Filter Posts which are posted within a three month ago in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, datetime, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In flask, i have this model:

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='N/A')
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

i wanna filter them by the posts posted within three month ago. Can somebody help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using months as a unit is a bit tricky because not all months contain the same number of days, so some edge cases may pop up. A quick and straightforward alternative (although less accurate) is to use weeks, and if you are ok with assuming 3 months ago is close to 12 weeks ago, you can implement the following

```
import datetime

today = datetime.today()
lower_bound = today - datetime.timedelta(weeks=12)
posts = BlogPost.query.filter(BlogPost.date_posted >= lower_bound)
```

The posts object should now filter to posts more recent than 12 weeks ago (roughly 3 months ago)